# Add element with single quote to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, escaping, quotes

I created dictionary in python like below:

```
flip= {'0': 'a"', '1':'b"', '2':'c"'}
```

But I don't want to use double quotes. I need elements with single quotes. 
How can I do something like below? I was trying with `\\`, `\`, but it seems not to work.

Correct dict should look like below:

```
flip= {'0': 'a'', '1':'b'', '2':'c''}
```

Comment: In the linked duplicate, it is explained for double quote. `"`. Similar approaches are applicable for single quotes `'` as well. It is explained in accepted answer to the linked post

Comment: The dictionary is irrelevant to the question. See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using backslash should work, have you tried below?

```
flip= {'0': 'a\'', '1':'b\'', '2':'c\''}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use double quotes around the element.

```
lip= {'0': "a'", '1':"b'", '2':"c'"}
```